# Unable to click cancel on the dialog box in IE 11 browser

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Not able to click on the message dialog box in IE 11 browser and also not able to inspect element of the box.

I have tried below code but **didn't quite work**:

1. **Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
   alert().dismiss();**
2. **Tried with AutoIT**

Using **sikuli** I could click on cancel button but I am looking for other options.

[image: Dialog box]

Comment: Do you use IE11 or The Edge browser which based on IE11?

Comment: I am using IE11 browser.

Comment: not working means? did you got any exception? try Keys like Cancel by robot class or try javascriptExecution?

Comment: Untill either of the options are clicked,unable to proceed with the automation.And also i am not getting any exceptions or any other error message.

Comment: Does the python code raise and Exception after failing to Dismiss the popup?

Comment: We are using java for automation. When I close IE browser manually,I am getting  "No Alert is active' exception when I use this below code  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();     alert().dismiss();

Comment: You can try with only driver.switchTo().alert(); alert().dismiss(); . and just ignore the Alert Assignment

Comment: I have tried  driver.switchTo().alert(); alert().dismiss(); without alert assignment,but it didn't work for me.

Comment: what about this: driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss(); ?

Comment: or   Robot rob = new Robot();
  rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
  rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);